# W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache?

Tags: nginx, cache, php-fpm, wordpress

I'm just preparing the **setup of a new VPS** where I will migrate a WordPress blog with a good traffic (currently, around 40k pageviews a day), and I was thinking about the caching strategy.

I've found different ideas and recommendations, but from previous experiences I will setup a **Nginx+PHP-FPM+MySQL** (LEMP) system on a Linode VPS. I've read also about setting Nginx as a **reverse proxy** with Apache, and even using **Varnish** too, but I don't know if all of this can benefit the speed/performance of the blog (that's the only thing that will be installed on the VPS).

The question now is... **would you recommend W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache?** I've used W3 on some blogs, but I haven't noticed great benefits and don't need all its options, so I think I could give the veteran WP Super Cache a try. Besides, some users have complained about W3 complex configuration and lack of performance (even consumig more CPU) on some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a **pretty thorughtful comparison** with several caching plugins for WordPress that explains with some detail their pros and cons

http://cd34.com/blog/scalability/wordpress-cache-plugin-benchmarks/

This one is also interesting:

http://cd34.com/blog/scalability/wordpress-cache-plugin-benchmarks/

Chris_O, thank you for your answer: in fact, I guess **that is true for every plugin** (not only caching) that works with WordPress, though there are always some cache plugins simpler and more "novice user" oriented.

W3 Total Cache seems nice if you're going to take advantage of all its features. If you don't, I'd say you better go for a simpler solution like WP Super Cache or Hyper Cache. **The performance is very good in all cases**, and caching WP is just something that should be mandatory. I think the people at Automattic should work a little bit on this aspect.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the problems people have with W3 Total Cache is not setting it up and reading the documentation properly.  For W3 to really shine you need to use it with either APC or Memcached for your object and database caching.

Also the [W3 Total Cache Development](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/324246) version contains native support for Nginx and will generate the correct rewrite rules.